# Bulleted list from dashes

Tags: php, regex

Let's keep this simple.

Input:

```
- abc
- def
- ghi
```

Desired output (whitespace optional):

```
<ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>def</li>
    <li>ghi</li>
</ul>
```

Current code:

```
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    "((^- (.*)$\r*\n*)+)m",
    function($m) {
        return "<ul><li>".
            implode(
                "</li><li>",
                preg_split(
                    "(^- )m",
                    substr($m[0],2)
                )
            ).
            "</li></ul>";
    },
    $input
);
```

It works, the output is exactly what I want, but it seems kinda... hackish. Having a `preg_split` inside a `preg_replace_callback` seems a bit redundant, but I can't seem to find a way of capturing subpatterns that are inside a quantifier. If I could do that then I would `implode` the subpatterns rather than having to split the matched part again.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you need to handle nested lists? Because that won't work with a regex.

Comment: Nested lists would be nice, but not required. That said, if you know a good piece of code for nested lists, please do share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't this give you the desired output:

```
$result = '<ul>' . preg_replace('/^- (.*)$/m', '<li>$1</li>', $subject) . '</ul>';
```

**Update:**

```
$output = preg_replace_callback(
    "((^- (.*)$\r*\n*)+)m",
    function($m) {
        return '<ul>' . preg_replace('/^- (.*)$/m', '<li>$1</li>', $m) . '</ul>';
    },
    $input
);
```

Comment: Not really, because the list may be inside a bigger string - I guess I should've mentioned that, but the string might have text before and after the list.

Comment: Oh, I see. My option will place the ul before all text, instead of before the list items. You could however use the replace in your callback.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to do this in two passes:

1. replace `- foo` by `<li>foo</li>` in every line
2. detect blocks of list items and add `<ul></ul>` around them

The code looks pretty straigtforward to me:

```
$output_li = preg_replace("/^- (.*)$/m", "<li>$1</li>", $input);
$output = preg_replace("/((<li>.*<\/li>\n)+)/m", "<ul>\n$1</ul>\n", $output_li);
```

If you want to allow nested lists, you might also want to allow other constructions. Why not use a php port of markdown then? If it's only about nested lists, a way to do that would be to use a recursive descent parser which would call itself whenever there is a new indentation level.

Comment: What if there's already a list? You would end up wrapping an extra `<ul>..</ul>` around it...

Comment: You could add a third pass to remove them, but it would then be more hackish than your original solution. :)